# jQuery: Change image src & class onclick

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, onclick

jQuery:

```
$(".upvote").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    var changeImage = ($(this).children('img').attr('src') === siteUrl + '/images/icon-upvote.png')
                    ? siteUrl + '/images/icon-upvote-inactive.png' 
                    : siteUrl + '/images/icon-upvote.png';
    $(this).children('img').attr('src', changeImage);

    var changeClass = ($(this).children('img').attr('src') === siteUrl + '/images/icon-upvote.png')
                    ? 'vote-icon' 
                    : 'vote-icon semi-transparent-more';
    $(this).children('img').attr('class', changeClass);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'comic=' + id + '&type=upvote',
        url: siteUrl + '/vote.php',
        success: function() {
            // PHP does all checks
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="vote.php?comic=$fileName&amp;type=upvote" id="$fileName" class="upvote$guestLink" onclick="return false;">$upvoteImage</a>
</div>
<div style="margin: 5px 0 8px 0;">
    <span class="score$scoreStyle bold" id="$fileName">$fileScore</span>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="vote.php?comic=$fileName&amp;type=downvote" class="downvote$guestLink">$downvoteImage</a>
</div>
```

This is what I've got and it works really well. Problem is I know there's a way to make this a tad more efficient than what I have.

Also, how can I select that span to change it's value? And how would I go about adjusting the value based on what is currently set within it? I've been struggling on this for the longest time.

Comment: I would suggest that you write your questions in the beginning of your posts. Having to read through 30 lines of code before even knowing what to look for might turn some people off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".upvote").click(function() {
    var id = this.id,
        $img = $(this).children('img'),
        changeImage,
        changeClass;

    if ($img.attr('src') === siteUrl + '/images/icon-upvote.png') {
        changeImage = siteUrl + '/images/icon-upvote-inactive.png';
        changeClass = 'vote-icon';
    } else {
        changeImage = siteUrl + '/images/icon-upvote.png';
        changeClass = 'vote-icon semi-transparent-more';
    }

    $img.attr({'src' : changeImage,
               'class' : changeClass });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'comic=' + id + '&type=upvote',
        url: siteUrl + '/vote.php',
        success: function() {
            // PHP does all checks
        }
    });
});
```

What I've changed:

1. Setting the `id` variable: given that in the function `this` is the DOM element, you can say `this.id` directly instead of creating a jQuery object with `$(this).attr('id')`
2. Cache your main jQuery object: rather than repeating `$(this).children('img')` (I've created a variable `$img` for this.)
3. Added an if/else: the ternary operator `?` is nice in a general sense, but you were using it twice (once for `changeImage` and once for `changeClass`) to evaluate the same condition. To me it makes more sense to evaluate that condition once in an `if` and then set both variables.
4. Changing the attributes: you were calling `.attr()` twice, but you can pass it a map of attributes and change them all at once.

> Also, how can I select that span to change it's value? And how would I go about adjusting the value based on what is currently set within it?

Well it would be a little easier to select if it was a child of the same div as the up and down anchor elements, but anyway for your structure maybe something like this:

```
// within the click handler for the upvote:
var $score = $(this).parent().next().find("span");
// or within the handler for the downvote:
var $score = $(this).parent().prev().find("span");
```

Note also that you've given that span an id that is the same as the id of the anchor element above it - this makes your html invalid because id should be unique on the page. I assume that you can't select by id though because you have multiple voting elements on the page.

As far as setting the value, to get the current value and increment in JS:

```
$score.html(function(i, oldHTML) {
   return +oldHTML + 1;
});
```

The syntax of passing a callback to [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) gives you a parameter with the old value and then you return the new value to set. So `+oldHTML` converts the string to a number - obviously I'm assuming here the span contains nothing but a number - and then adds one to it.

However, I think it would be better to do that in your ajax success handler using data from the server: have your PHP code return the new value and then in the success handler apply that value.

Comment: This is excellent. I really appreciate these insightful explanations for answers, it helps me better understand improving code for the future. Thanks! Any chance you can guide me on grabbing that span's content?